# Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: user lacks privilege

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

Seems that I don't know what I lack. After running JUnit Test, a got this

`Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DTB_TABLENAME {Insert into ....`

Does this have something to do with my database? or the code itself?

here are some codes:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myrestapi" transaction-type="JTA">
    <class>com.rest.entity.TableNameBean</class>

    <jta-data-source>MyDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

**MyGenericDao**

```
public abstract class MyGenericDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MyGenericDao() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}
//....
//....

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T findById(ID id, boolean lock) {
    if(lock)
        return getEntityManager().find(getPersistentClass(), id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    else
        return getEntityManager().find(getPersistentClass(), id);
}

public T makePersistent(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

**[TableName]Dao**

```
 @Singleton
public class TableNameDao extends GenericJpaDao<TableNameBean, Integer>{

@PersistenceContext(unitName="myrestapi")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
  }
```

Then, my **TableNameDaoTest**

```
public class TableNameDaoTest {

private static EJBContainer container;

@EJB
private TableNameDao tableNameDao;

@Test
public void testFindById() {
    TableNameBean tableBean = tableNameDao.findById(1, false);
    assertNotNull(tableBean);
}

@Test
public void testFindAll() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testMakePersistent() {
    TableNameBean tableBean = new TableNameBean();
    tableBean.setLoginName("testname");
    tableBean.setPassword("password");

    tableNameDao.makePersistent(tableBean);
    assertNotNull(tableBean.getAccountId());
}

@BeforeClass
public static void start() {
    container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
}

@Before
public void inject() throws NamingException {
    container.getContext().bind("inject", this);
}

@AfterClass
public static void stop() {
    container.close();
}
```

Any help on this one, please? Thanks a lot. Btw, Im running on TomEE and also my database is MySql. I've also configured my database url, driver, username and password in `tomee.xml`. I've also imported it to my Server folder and published.